# Help with this kernel panic log please!

Tags: kernel-panic

Could any of you guys help me understand what caused my MacBook to crash please? Thanks a lot!

```
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff800696cce8): "cluster_push_err: Expected NULL cl_scmap\n"@/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-6153.141.33/bsd/vfs/vfs_cluster.c:5696
mp = 0xffffff8019440b20, phys = 0x1f5c31b20, prev (0xb: 0xffe70000-0xffea0000)
vp = 0xffffff8024a5a200, phys = 0x17e41b200, prev (0xb: 0xffe70000-0xffea0000)
0xffffff801943f000: 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
0xffffff8019440000: 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
0xffffff8019441000: jwAAAJYAAAChAAAAAgICAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKDxqLjhAWAAABCiEIBAEDGGw4JBonKg0ICAFr94A2oAgqqhoAYCAgIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAICAgCoqKioAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIBAGh8aBwAAICAKAQYRQAAhEQAACAwAAAAAAAAAACAxMQAvZGV2L2Rpc2szczEAEA8dgP///wAAAAQAAQAAAABAAAMAAAAAEAAAD3gWAItJBgAAAAAhAD6/HAkAAACAUgAdAG8xHZTVrTMgBUoeAAAAAvyTvG7U7v/AByD+BwDJsomAeAYHAHCpJoAVRBkZkjAEAAB9kQYBAAAAACAAdksAADItAABEHgAADwAAARcAAABoZnMAL1ZvbHVtZXMvRjAzRjRCNUYtQzQ0OS00NkMwLUI4RTMtNEE1N0FCMzg3OUQAAC9Wb2x1bWVzL0YwM0Y0QjVGLUM0NDktNDZDMC1COEUzLTRBNTdBQjM4NzlERQAvZGV2L2Rpc2s1czEA2O4aAAAgAAACAAAAACAAAwAAAAAAACEHIAAAByD+BwDK0CoBAAAAonV8KvyTvG4AAPDA7u7gDuDu7u5DbuPuAAAOAADgDg4AAA0AAYAQAI/9DzgBbA44TwjwP38DDhmgvT8j9RUBOACCEAAC/A84JvxfHxQ4IQAA
Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff912de839d0 : 0xffffff800671c63d 
0xffffff912de83a20 : 0xffffff8006856b25 
0xffffff912de83a60 : 0xffffff80068486ae 
0xffffff912de83ab0 : 0xffffff80066c2a40 
0xffffff912de83ad0 : 0xffffff800671bd07 
0xffffff912de83bd0 : 0xffffff800671c0f7 
0xffffff912de83c20 : 0xffffff8006ec0b3c 
0xffffff912de83c90 : 0xffffff800696cce8 
0xffffff912de83d00 : 0xffffff7f881497e8 
0xffffff912de83d70 : 0xffffff7f881797ff 
0xffffff912de83da0 : 0xffffff8006975b77 
0xffffff912de83e50 : 0xffffff7f88175bad 
0xffffff912de83ea0 : 0xffffff800698777a 
0xffffff912de83ec0 : 0xffffff80069757fc 
0xffffff912de83f30 : 0xffffff8006987687 
0xffffff912de83f40 : 0xffffff8006d83cb7 
0xffffff912de83fa0 : 0xffffff80066c3206 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.filesystems.apfs(1412.141.2)[FF6AC682-EBE4-356D-B683-5A07BDB7CC07]@0xffffff7f88114000->0xffffff7f8823bfff
            dependency: com.apple.kec.corecrypto(1.0)[6333D455-80A5-3129-8E34-5EA8A3C27312]@0xffffff7f876b5000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage(1.0)[D1098090-E2B5-337E-AE67-4E79EC26EAF9]@0xffffff7f87e1c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.1)[E5EEA957-1FBA-354A-A334-78116167B91E]@0xffffff7f87310000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: launchd

Mac OS version:
19H1217

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Thu May  6 00:48:39 PDT 2021; root:xnu-6153.141.33~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 0B6CD26B-B526-3646-9B69-02D22BBE9C52
Kernel slide:     0x0000000006400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8006600000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8006500000
System model name: MacBookPro9,2 (Mac-6F01561E16C75D06)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 1472527415485051
last loaded kext at 1454539442275226: >usb.cdc.acm  5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f89e47000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 1458689339681229: >usb.cdc    5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f89e1e000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
@filesystems.smbfs  3.4.4
>AudioAUUC  1.70
@fileutil   20.036.15
>AGPM   111.4.4
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!AMikeyHIDDriver   131
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.2.7
>!A!IHD4000Graphics 14.0.7
>!AMikeyDriver  283.15
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.2.7
>eficheck   1
>!AHDA  283.15
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.6f8
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
>SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
>!ASMCPDRC  1.0.0
>pmtelemetry    1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!ALPC  3.1
>!ASMCLMU   212
>!ABacklight    180.3
>!AFWOHCI   5.6.2
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
>!A!IFramebufferCapri   14.0.7
>!UTCButtons    255
>!UTCKeyboard   255
>!AIR!C 360
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.141.2
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASDXC 1.7.7
|!ABCM5701Ethernet  10.3.5
>AirPort.Brcm4360   1400.1.1
>!AAHCIPort 341.140.1
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ARTC  2.0
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
>!A!ICPUPowerManagementClient   222.0.0
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
>!A!ICPUPowerManagement 222.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
@kext.triggers  1.0
|IOFireWireIP   2.3.0
|IOAVB!F    850.1
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
>!AGraphicsControl  5.2.7
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  576.1
@!AGPUWrangler  5.2.7
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
|IOFireWire!F   4.7.5
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.7.4
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.2.7
|IOGraphics!F   576.1
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   7.0.6f8
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.6f8
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.6f8
|IO!B!F 7.0.6f8
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.6f8
>!UMultitouch   264
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>usb.!UHub  1.2
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOSurface  269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.1
|IOAHCIBlock!S  316.100.5
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
>usb.!UEHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UEHCI 1.2
|IOAHCI!F   290.0.1
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.120.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.120.3
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.140.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.120.3
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a synchronous panic in the APFS driver. Your filesystem is almost certainly corrupted.

1. You need to **immediately stop using your computer** to avoid further corrupting the filesystem.
2. Boot into Recovery mode (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> during boot) in order to try to run **Disk First Aid** to repair the filesystem.
3. Whether or not DFA succeeds, your next step should be to create a **backup** of your documents, starting with the most important ones first, if you do not already have an up-to-date backup. In case DFA fails to repair the drive, this should be done via **[Target Disk Mode](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/transfer-files-mac-computers-target-disk-mode-mchlp1443/mac)**, *not* booted into your Mac, to minimize further corruption.
4. If DFA can not repair the drive, you will need to **erase** it and reinstall macOS, then restore your documents from the backup.

If this panic reoccurs after either a successful repair or a full erase & install, then there is a persistent underlying cause of corruption, such as faulty DRAM or SSD devices. These are less common than idiopathic corruption.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! The problem is coming from the main Hard Drive "Macintosh HD"? Because I have two hard drives in Mac, and the main one is a brand new Crucial MX.

Comment: @Falconx The panic report does not include information about which drive's filesystem is at fault. In general it is more likely to be your boot drive (sounds like that's your new Crucial MX). Keep in mind that the drive hardware may be operating correctly and this is simply the result of a software error, or it might indeed be a hardware fault. There are a lot of possible root causes and no way to differentially diagnose one from a single panic report. Let's start by scanning both filesystems in Recovery mode.

Comment: I scanned both hard drives and they seem to be okay. I use the second hard drive as a file storage drive. What do you think?

Comment: @Falconx If you've made a full backup of your drive, then you can resume using your Mac as normal. There is always the chance that (1) that panic was spurious (e.g., it was the result of a cosmic ray flipping a runtime bit as opposed to permanent corruption on the volume), (2) the filesystem is damaged in a way that Disk Utility's heuristics are unable to detect, or (3) there is a different root cause (e.g., a bug in the APFS driver, or an unrelated hardware fault) which happened to indirectly trigger this panic.

Comment: In case (1) you are unlikely to see a recurrence of that panic in the near future. In cases (2) and (3), you may. All you can really do right now is observe and keep making regular backups. (And make sure to routinely SCAN your backups with Disk First Aid to ensure that *they* don't propagate any corruption!)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I ended up doing a clean install of Catalina.

Comment: @Falconx Great, I hope that that resolves your issue! If you're satisfied with my answer, would you mind marking it as accepted? Thanks!